# 'getFormattedPrice' undefined on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, knockoutjs, knockout

I need to get a list under each product in the form:
 - Unit price
 - Amount
 - Amount based on price and quantity

Rewrite template:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`

my Template

```
<div class="product-item-details">
    <div class="product-item-inner">
        <div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Price' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.price"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code block

```
<div class="price">
    <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Price' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.price"></span>
</div>
```

Must give a formatted price: `1.780,00 €`

But on the front end, I see: `1780`

I used the method: `getFormattedPrice($parent.price)`

but i was getting undefined

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't also overwrite the js file for your template, the method `getFormattedPrice` is not defined in your component. That is why you get undefined when trying to use `getFormattedPrice`.

If you didn't overwrite it then the component for your tempalte is this one: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js` .

The file `src/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js` defines the `getFormattedPrice` method you want to use.

I see 2 easy ways to fix this, so you can use `getFormattedPrice` in your template:

A) Extend `details.js` and implement `getFormattedPrice` the same way like `abstract-total.js`

B) Overwrite `details.js`  and extend from `abstract-total.js` so you can use `getFormattedPrice` in your template

Comment: I rewrite in
`app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js` and add
`getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
        }`
+ and added  define `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',`

but it didn’t work, please help

Comment: still the same that you get undefined as result ? did you check if it uses the new version of your file ? (for example by having a look in the sources using the browser console)

Comment: oh, understand, I did not delete the cache, now everything is fine, thanks